# Computer hard shutdown and won't let me restart until I cycle the PSU

Tags: power-supply, shutdown

My build
Windows 10 home x64
MB: [Crosshair VII Hero](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-CROSSHAIR-VII-HERO/specifications/)
Processor: Ryzen 7 2700x
Ram: CORSAIR Vengeance RGB Pro 32GB (4 x 8 GB)
Vid: [ASUS ROG GeForce GTX 1080 Ti DirectX 12 Strix](https://www.asus.com/us/Graphics-Cards/ROG-STRIX-GTX1080TI-O11G-GAMING/specifications/)
HDD: 1x500G m.2,  3 various sized SSDs, 1 old style 1T, 2 USB ext. drives.
Cooling: [NZXT x62 liquid cooled](https://www.nzxt.com/products/kraken-x62)
PSU: EVGA SuperNOVA G3, 1000W

I have nothing over clocked, everything is less than 3 months old.

After I wiped my computer about 2 weeks ago, I have issues with the computer hard shutting down randomly, and when I try to reboot it, it won't do anything until I switch the PSU power off and on. While in the shutdown state, the LED's on the mother board stay on (the decorative ones) so I know the PSU is still supplying power.

What I have done:

Yesterday, I re-installed all drivers including BIOS, performed stress tests on both the CPU and the video card continuous for 5 hours (100% load), and did not have it trip once. I thought I had fixed it. But I woke this morning to it being in the shutdown state and I had to cycle PSU again.

Temps when idle are 28°C, at 100% load 55°C (CPU) and 62°C (vid).

I will say there was something odd, too, in my early stages of diagnosing.  I thought it would be thermal Shut Down related, so I installed a monitor (CoreTemp), through the one night it recorded a max temp hit of 197°C, but didn't shut down. I found this very strange.

Comment: “197°C“ - Sounds like a sensor error, if any chip was that hot, nothing would would be left.  That’s 97 degrees hotter then required to boil water.  “I thought it would be thermal SD related, so I installed a monitor” - Can you clarify what you installed exactly and what “SD” is exactly.  Edit your question

Comment: May I suggest you a) remove all of the RAM, and reinstall one only for overnight testing? If it fails, replace it with another RAM module and repeat. b) Remove the cooler and CPU, clean the thermal interface material away, reseat the CPU, apply new thermal material, and reseat the cooler. Once you have done so, click on `edit` above and to the left to update your original post with the new findings.  c) Also, it takes a double-space after a line to create a newline in this software which runs this site.

Answer (score 1):

Motherboard LEDs are powered by the +5VSB rail, and while it is a good sign, this does not neccesarily means the PSU's main rails are working or the PSU as a whole is performing correctly.

Temp of 197º as some people stated in the comments seems like a bad sensor. I have seen many of this cases, specially on high end boards with lots of sensors, I'd just ignore it.

About your issue, It is impossible to diagnose it properly with the data we have... but with the symptoms you describe I would say is probably a faulty PSU or motherboard. A short circuit on other place can also trigger a protection from the psu and force a turn off to rearm.

Please edit with PSU model if you can check it. Brand (and OEM) is quite important, wattage alone means close to nothing on a PSU.

Another intereting test you can perform, if you have a multimiter available, is to unplug the internal cables of the PSU when the pc does not boot, short the green cable with any black cable of the ATX connector (that makes the PSU turn on), and carefully measure voltage in all rails. If the PSU does not power on, you have a candidate for the problems. A paper clip is very convenient for this: https://www.silverstonetek.com/downloads/QA/PSU/PSU-Paper%20Clip-EN.pdf

Comment: I will try those tonight, I could also check how dirty the power is I guess (i have all the gadgets), that could be a concern too I guess. All edits requested have been done.

Comment: Ok, so last night I tested my PSU, everything checked out fine, proper voltages and no ripple or surges (while I had the scope on it anyways) that I could find. I started out pulling all but one stick of ram and while I was at it I started looking through the software that controls the lighting on them, apparently my ram requires drivers. This made me think of a problem I had when initially building the computer, I couldn't set their clock speed to what they were rated for without crashing. After 15 hours of stress testing, everything seems ok, to early to be sure, I will update if it changes.